# Bootstrap sticky footer overlapping content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap, and I'm trying to use it with Symfony2. I already have a main topbar sticky which is used for navigation. My problem is when I try to add a similar footer which is sticky at the bottom, but it overlaps my content. I'm using a JQuery script to avoid the problem for the top navbar, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document.body).css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height());
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $(document.body).css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height());
        });
    });
```

The structure of my main Twig layout is like this:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="topnavbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    </footer>
```

My CSS is original. I tried with `margin bottom` or `padding bottom` but the overlapping of my content (in the {% block body %}) is always present, and I don't know what to do to fix it.  Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 37):

This is an older topic with no answer selected.

I am on a fresh Bootstrap template, porting his current theme to Bootstrap section by section :)

I have a sticky header, and want the footer locked to the bottom at **ALL** times. I had it working, but when I re-sized it to view it responsive, the footer overlapped the content. I needed a padding/space between the "content" and the "footer" so it didn't look mushed together.

margin-bottom on the body tag did not work, it added a gap below my footer. When you think about how a margin behaves on the "body" tag, that only makes sense.

The correct answer is to use "padding-bottom" on the body tag. I used a size 6 pixels larger than the height of my footer to ensure this small padding/spacing.

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 114px;
}
```

Your heights would be different of course. Hope this helps!

Comment: It is worth noting that a fixed navbar at the top requires a [padding-top](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) to the body and similarly a fixed footer requires a padding-bottom

Comment: And how exactly is `position: absolute` supposed to fix the overlapping problem?

Comment: This padding-bottom made all the difference !

Comment: **TL;DR** : `body {padding-bottom: 50px;}` with `50px` being your footer height plus an additional margin (+1)

Comment: This was the aha moment i had that helped save me hours of trying to adjust. In my case I was using a sticky header and a fixed footer. I switched the header to fixed and added padding to the top/bottom based on size of footer/header. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 14):

There is a new modern flex-box based solution.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Hey</header>
  <main>Here some content</main>
  <footer>And a perfect sticky footer without overlapping</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You also need `margin:0` on `body`. Browser default is `8px`.

Comment: Issue is that you have to scroll to see the footer. How would you make the footer fit into the viewport such that the body takes e.g. 90% of the height and the footer takes 10%?

Answer (score 13):

As standard, this is expected behaviour for Bootstrap headers and footers - they stick to the top or bottom, and overlap the main content.  The solution for footers is to add `margin-bottom: [footer height];` to the `body`, as in the [customisation example on the Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/):

*sticky-footer.css*

```
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

You mention `margin-bottom` in your question, so if that doesn't work for you maybe you could post what you actually tried?

P.S. This is probably nothing to do with Symfony!

Comment: Here is the screen of this result : 
[link](http://i.imgur.com/0RCYehs.png) I have try a lot of thing like 
body { margin: 0 0 60px; } or change my jquery script with adding bottom.nav like :$(document.body).css('margin-bottom', $('#botnavbar').height()); (with right id on my footer). But nothing worked so far.

Comment: I think it'll be hard to help without the actual code - the HTML for the page, and the CSS.  Is there any particular reason you're using JQuery rather than just making changes directly to CSS?

Comment: I use it for the responsive i don't know if this help but this work for me . I'm looking for [exemple](http://jeremie.patonnier.net/pages/mentions-legales) this footer but i don't understand why there is always an overlap i'm adding a margin-bottom with like 110 % it work but if i add a content then i need to define an other margin bottom. (The margin bottom works only if i disable the script)

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi Zache, please try to avoid answering with plain code. Please include explanations to your answer so that the OP can understand why you used it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `container-fluid` `height` to `auto`. I also had this issue and this solution worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Posting here because this is what Google returned when searching how to fix overlapping footer.

With Bootstrap 5 create a sticky footer that doesn't overlap by wrapping the footer in a clearfix tag per the documentation like this:

```html
<div class="clearfix">...</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/helpers/clearfix/

If you are not sure how to get a footer to stick to the bottom of the page add a flexbox class to your body like this:

```html
<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">...</body>
```

Then add flex-grow-1 to the div/section before the footer in your template. This cause's it's box to fill available space and pushes the footer to the bottom.

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">...</div>
```