# table displaying over footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I prevent the content of a long table or list from displaying over my footer if it takes up more than 100% of the height of the screen? I'd like the table to be responsive and take up the entire div. I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336190/bootstrap-sticky-footer-overlapping-content/29284379) but manually setting the bottom-margin did not help. My current ad-hoc solution is to manually limit the table height to prevent if from spilling over the footer. Below is the *index.html* that extends from *base.html*

```css
/* style.css */

html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

div#sp500Table.table-responsive {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!--base.html -->

<body class="bg-dark text-white container-fluid">

  <header class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark">
    ...
  </header>

  <main role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex">
      {% block body %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="page-footer font-small fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      ...
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>


<!-- index.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block body %}
<div class="table-responsive" id="sp500Table">
  <table class="table table-light table-striped table-sm" id="sp500Table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr> {% for col in table_header %}
        <th>{{ col }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> {% for num, r in enumerate(payload) %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ num+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.get('symbol') }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.get('security') }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ r.get('sec_filings') }}" target="_blank">link</a></td>
        <td>{{ r.get('sector') }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.get('sub_sector') }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.get('headquarters') }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.get('date_first_added') }}</td>
      </tr> {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the table into a div and add a height to the div. The add overflow: auto to the div. This will prevent table from taking up more space than you want and still allow you to scroll through all the page content.

Comment: My table is already inside a div and the style.css file has the overflow-y set. How can I set the height to be the remaining height of the page without setting it manually to 500px?

Comment: There are various ways to do it, you could use a percentage height for elements on your page using something like vh, or you could position your elements with flex box, you could also use css calc to come up with a custom calculation for your height, but I wouldnt reccoment the last one.

Comment: Could you update your answer with the first two options? I've found a 2010 question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space] and I am frozen by information overload. What I gathered was flex box is the modern approach and vh may? work with a unknown header and footer height if I use a div inside a div.